# elegant way to call async functions in a match statement, in F#

Tags: f#

This cannot work:

```
let a () =
    async {
        return 0
    }
    
let b x =
    async {
        return
            match x with
            | true ->
                let! y = a()  <- you can't compile this
                y
            | false ->
                0
    }
```

I understand I could do this:

```
let b x =
    async {
        match x with
        | true ->
            return! a()
        | false ->
            return 0
    }
```

but there are cases where I need a:

```
let! y = a()
```

to do more operations with the result.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you combine the two?

```ml
let b x =
    async {
        match x with
        | true ->
            let! y = a()
            return y
        | false ->
            return 0
    }
```

Comment: not necessarily because I may need the result of that match to continue the flow. For example, getting data whether a cache is empty or not, I need the result which may have done async calls, or not to get the data

Comment: @Thomas unfortunately you're probably going to have to have some nested asyncs. There's not really a better way right now (until we get a bind operator that can be arbitrarily deep :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can move the async expression inside each case:

```
let b x =
  match x with
  | true -> async {
      let! y = a ()
      ...
      return y
    }
  | false -> async { return 0 }
```

Comment: yes, I know, but I was hoping they'd be some syntactic form I don't know about :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you think this is more elegant, but more functions usually makes it look a bit nicer, here's an example:

```
module Async =
  let create v = async { return v }
  let bind f a = async.Bind (a, f)
  let map f a =
    bind (f >> create) a


let a () = Async.create 0

let addOne y =
  y + 1

let b x =
  match x with
  | true -> a () |> Async.map addOne
  | false -> Async.create 0
  // Additional piping to map or bind if you wish, e.g:
  // |> Async.bind ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the return inside the match.

```
let a () = async {
    return 0
}
    
let b x = async {
    match x with
    | true  -> return! a()
    | false -> return  0
}
```

Otherwise you can do this:

```
module Async =
    let create x = async { return x }

let a () = async {
    return 10
}
    
let b x = async {
    let! x1 =
        match x with
        | true  -> a()
        | false -> async { return 0 }
    
    let! x2 =
        if x then a() else Async.create 0

    // Do whatever with x1 or x2
    return x2
}
```

Create a function for code that occur often:

```
let whatever b a x = 
    if x then a() else Async.create x

let! y = whatever b a 0
```

Comment: this will not compile as well, like my example: "This construct may only be used within computation expressions"

Comment: @THomas Hmm, interesting, when i tried it, it worked on my machine, now it doesn't. ...

Comment: @Thomas Changed code, now working. Don't know if you think it is better or not. But i'm not even sure anymore what you really want to achieve.

Comment: That's the same as Lee's solution, which is the way I was doing it before; I was hoping for some syntactic trick or idea to solve this.

Comment: @Thomas Seems there is none. But if you have this kind of code multiple times. You always can create a function. For example take the code in the `x2` binding, create a function and provide `x`, `a` and the else value `0` as a function argument.